# Adding object into Array of of Objects, Nodejs, Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm working on a small app where you can add products into a users cart.

I have a route set up for adding a specified product into a cart and that works fine. However when I add it in, all that shows up the array is the _id of the product, when what I'm looking for is an object containing some information (i.e, product name, product price, etc.). So that I can access it later in my React-Redux App. I've found a few suggestions online, but they either seem to not work for me at all or give me the same thing I've been getting.

Heres the route:

```
Cart.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
      .then(cart => {
        Product.findById(req.params.product_id).then(product => {
          const newItem = {}
          newItem._id = product._id; 
          newItem.name = product.name;
          newItem.price = product.price;
          const total =
            parseFloat(cart.total) + parseFloat(product.price);
          cart.total = Math.round(total*100)/100;


          cart.items.push(newItem);
          cart.save().then(cart=> res.json(cart));
        });
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
```

Here's the corresponding Schema:

```
        const CartSchema = new Schema({
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "users"
      },
      total: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
      },
      items: [
        {
          product: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "product"
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Your schema is set up to only store the `_id` and a ref to the **product** collection. You might want to look at Mongoose’s **populate** method: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the product as is. Maybe because of the schema a `Product` is expected by mongoose, not a generic object such as, in your case, `newItem`

```
Cart.findOne({ user: req.user.id }).then(cart => {
  return Product.findById(req.params.product_id);
}).then(product => {
  const total = parseFloat(cart.total) + parseFloat(product.price);
  cart.total = Math.round(total*100)/100;
  cart.items.push(product);
  return cart.save();
}).then(cart => {
  return res.json(cart)
}).catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
```

NOTE: i also fixed your promise chain structure a bit. This way you avoid callback hell, and only need one catch statement for the whole chain of promises.

Comment: That still ends up with me having only the ID stored in the array, although that did fix my "unhandled callback exception errors" which were super annoying, Thank you

Comment: Hmm, try a `console.log(product)` just after `.then(product => {` to see what are the contents of the object

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
const CartSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "users"
    },
    total: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },
    items: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "product"
        }
    ]
});
```

And item pushed to array of items should be instance of Product, not just plain object.

Comment: I still end up with having only the ID stored in the array and not the object. Is it something to do with the type of the object? Would changing it to a generic object perhaps be better?